# jQuery not functioning without document.ready on a cfm page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm pretty new to jQuery, and I am converting a page from "regular" javascript to jQuery on a coldfusion page.  The page is driven off a stored procedure, which, based on it's result sets, changes the page and number of input fields. On my page, the input tags look like this.

```
<cfinput name="#trim(characteristic_id)#_fund" id="#trim(characteristic_id)#_fund" value="#fund#" size="11" onFocus="getCurrentValue(this)" onblur="checkChange(this,'c')">
<cfinput name="#trim(characteristic_id)#_benchmark" id="#trim(characteristic_id)#_benchmark" value="#benchmark#" size="11" onFocus="getCurrentValue(this)" onblur="checkChange(this,'c')">
```

The `onFocus` event just saves the current value, and the `onBlur` event checks to see if the value has changed, and if it has save it in a array for further processing.

Personally, I feel like jQuery is suited very well for this kind of processing, and it is on of the main reason I am trying it.

To my issue. Right now I am replacing the `onFocus` event handler with:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

simple, but when I try i, nothing happens, no javascript errors, nothing. Nothing happens at all.  So, all of the other jQuery code that I have written, I have used `$(document).ready...`, and when I used that, it worked fine.  From what I've read, the UI is rendered before the DOM is ready, but to compound that issue the coldfusion is running prior to everything else.

My question is this; Do I have to put all of my jQuery code inside the `$(document).ready...` function or is there another way around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you simply move your jQuery to the bottom the page before the `</body>` like it should be anyway, you wouldn't have to worry about `$(document).ready` because it will be ready by the time it gets there.  Trying that would at least rule that out for you.

Comment: so moving the jquery below the `</body>` tag is the accepted way to code jquery? Like i said, this is my first foray into using jquery.

Comment: No, right above it, including the reference to jQuery itself. Check out [Html5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) for all you want to know best practice wise.

Comment: That is some information.  Do you know if this still applies to `*.cfm` pages, or just `*.html` pages?

Comment: To be honest, I do not. I would assume it's the same. The reason you put it at the bottom is so the page loads faster, loading the scripts last.  The bonus is that you never have to check if the DOM is ready due to the fact that it's already ready by the time it gets there.

Comment: Makes sense.  I'll give it a try there and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to put your code in `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` if you want to attach handlers to DOM objects.  That being said, you *can* call code in a script block that loads after the element you want to manipulate and that should work, too.  However, it is good practice to use the ready/load handlers.

If you don't wait for the DOM to load, the elements don't exist yet.

You do not have to stuff all of your code in one ready block if you don't want to.  You can have multiple `$(document).ready()` blocks.  Each will simply be called in succession once the document loads.

`$(window).load()`, by the way, waits for the elements themselves to load, such as images.

Comment: So `$(document).ready(function(){ $("input").focus(...); $("input").blur(...);})` is acceptable as is `$(document).ready(function(){$("input").focus(...);}); $(document).ready(function(){$("input").blur(...);});` is also acceptable?

Comment: Yep.  That will work, although it is more overhead.  Also, your scopes won't be the same in those two `ready` functions, which shouldn't matter if your code is not related.

Comment: Does Scott's comments above still apply to this, moving the jquery to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but using a ready/load handler is better practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate the DOM, you should put your code inside [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code.